# How to change the Soap header message

Tags: spring, soap, soapui, soap-client, spring-ws

I have soap request to be sent to the service. Before sending i want to edit the Soap header

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
```

this is one of the header i want to pass the value of `mustUnderstand` as 0 not 1. Because i am getting one exception if i pass the value as 1. The exception i am getting with value 1 is:

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: One or more mandatory SOAP header blocks not understood
```

I have checked in the Soap UI by passing `mustUnderstand` value as 0 and it worked. Now i want to send the same thing from my client.

I tried to add parameter in application conext bean definition xml file but did not work out as per below

```
<property name="securementmustUnderstand"><value>false</value></property>
```

Please let me know how to change `mustUnderstand` parameter in my client.

The complete bean definion is below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="reg" class="com.service.RegConsServiceImpl">
        <property name="regWebServiceTemplate" ref="regWebServiceTemplate"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="regWebServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
        <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="unmarshaller"/>
        <property name="interceptors">          
            <list>
                <ref bean="wsRegClientSecurityInterceptor"/>
            </list>
        </property> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="wsRegClientSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="securementmustUnderstand">
            <value>false</value>
        </property>
        <property name="securementActions" value="UsernameToken" />
        <property name="securementPasswordType" value="PasswordText"/>
        <property name="securementPassword">
            <value>${registration.ws.password}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="securementUsername">
            <value>${registration.ws.username}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The below is the soap message got generated

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-3">
                <wsse:Username>test</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">test</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns3:GetRegInfo xmlns:ns3="http://www.test.com/regester" xmlns:ns2="http://www.test.com/regester2" xmlns:ns4="http://com.test.com.services.register">
            <ns3:personId>10</ns3:personId>
        </ns3:GetRegInfo>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: For which bean did you add that property? Please put hte whole `<bean >` element in your question instead of a snippet.

Comment: And are you actually using that template to construct the soap message? How do you create the message you want to send...

Comment: I am new to this Soap webservice. i am not sure how the soap message gets construct. I am using below code to send and receive the request and response 
regWebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request)

Where request is object of schema class which is has getter and setter methods of the fields which i am sending to web service.

Comment: enable logging and figure out what is getting send. When setting `org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing` to `trace` will give you the actual message being sent. Check which values are being set.

Comment: Please don't add it as comment, add it to your question...

Comment: Please check the edited question for the soap message generated. Some how i want to change the value of mustUnderstand to 0.

Comment: Are you sure that the bean definitions posted are the ones you use? Because `securementmustUnderstand` isn't valid for a property as it should be `securementMustUnderstand`.

Comment: I tried with both securementMustUnderstand and securementmustUnderstand, but every time its going as 1

Comment: If you also tried with `securementmustUnderstand` then I highly doubt the configuration is used... As the application would have failed to start in that case with an invalid property exception.

Comment: But i did not get any such exception. Is there any other way to change the header instead from the bean definition file.

Comment: As mentioned if you don't get the exception I highly doubt you are using this configuration file.

Comment: @lamps did you solve this issue?

Comment: @bpetlur , what is the alternative solution found ?